# Repository in T4 template

Tags: repository-pattern, entity-framework-4

I am writing a T4 template for repositories.

Say we have Customers/Orders/Products tables. We then have CustomerRepo, OrdersRepo, and ProductsRepo.

Is it a good practice to have a generic repo for all of them?

```
public partial class Repository
```

{

```
private IContext context;
public Repository()
{
    _Product = new ProductRepo();
    _Customer = new CustomerRepo();
}

public Repository(IContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
    _Product = new ProductRepo(context);
    _Customer = new CustomerRepo(context);
}

private ProductRepo _Product;
public ProductRepo Product {
    get { return _Product; }
}
// Product

private CustomerRepo _Customer;
public CustomerRepo Customer {
    get { return _Customer; }
}
// Customer
```

}

Comment: FYI: They all are repositories for each class in the DB. but I wanna make a generic one to encapsulate them, so they all have one point of entry, and allow easier access to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that it is best to make a repository for each type rather than one single repository.  Otherwise the repository tends to get large as all sorts of functionality is added.

Comment: I do have a repository for each type, but this "generic" repository would be an entry point for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can even look at implementing your repository like this [post](http://codepaste.net/u4bqq3). You can even extend the concept and implement generic and have `IRepository<T> where T:IEntity` and then have a base implementation called `BaseRepository<T>`.
Based on your additions to the question you might want to use Factory Pattern or Facade Pattern or Dependency Injection (using Unity/StructureMap container). It depends on how complex it is and how flexible your solution needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently reviewed a few implementations of Repository pattern with Entity frameworks  and found  https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/GenericRepository ( described  at http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle)
the most advanced.

If you will use GenericRepository  base class, I don't see  any benefits to generate derived classes using t4 template.